# Appium Testing with eclipse + testlaunch error

Tags: android, sdk, appium, launcher

im just in the beginning of learning Appium. Im stuck with a prob.Whenever i try to run the code, it gives me the following error.Kindly suggest the work which needs to be done.

```
This is the code:

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;
import org.junit.Test;
public class DesiredCapabilitesTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws MalformedURLException{

        File appDir=new File("src");
        File app=new File(appDir,"BookMyShow-Movie.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android Emulator");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,app.getAbsolutePath());

            AndroidDriver driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1.4723/wd/hub"),cap);

        }
    }
```

Here is the error:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

I have run the appium tool manually, but it just shows the following on the UI:

> info:[debug] Non default server args:
> info:Console log level:debug

Answer (score 0):

Your appium server is not running. So first of all start your appium server from desktop app or command line.